# how can i store list data in above variable lat ?Compiler throws key error list indices must be integer not str

Tags: python

```
def get_location(self):
    # get location
    location_req_url = "%s"% self.get_ip()
    print location_req_url
    lat = location_req_url['location'][0]["lat"]
    lon = location_req_url[0]["lng"]
    print lat
    print lon
    return {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}

def get_ip(self):
    ip_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyCpx2tKaiqlI6p7xgpCXK"
    req = requests.post(ip_url)
    ip_json = json.loads(req.text)
    print ip_json
    return ip_json
```

This the json data that I get in response:
{u'location': {u'lat': 20.2960587, u'lng': 85.8245398}, u'accuracy': 7500.0}

Answer (score 0):

You do not need index to access the lat and lng key from the response.

**Ex:**

```
 def get_location(self):
    # get location
    location_req_url = "%s"% self.get_ip()
    print location_req_url
    lat = location_req_url['location']["lat"]
    lon = location_req_url['location']["lng"]
    print lat
    print lon
    return {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}
```

**Output:**

```
{u'location': {u'lat': 20.2960587, u'lng': 85.8245398}, u'accuracy': 7500.0}
20.2960587
85.8245398
{'lat': 20.2960587, 'lon': 85.8245398}
```